# Bash command ls ordering options

Tags: bash, shell, ls

New here (and to coding). I'm writing a simple bash script that helps me change a character into another character in all files of the current directory. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#this script changes characters in all files of the current directory

NUM=$(ls -1 | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')

echo "There are $NUM files in this folder."
echo "Changing $1 to $2 in all their names..."
echo "Done! Here's what happened:"

for i in $(seq 1 $NUM)
do
    OLDNAME=$(ls -1 | head -$i | tail -1)
    NEWNAME=$(ls -1 | head -$i | tail -1 | sed -e "s/${1}/${2}/g")
    mv -v "$OLDNAME" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

So if I write `./ccin.sh " " "_"` it should be changing all spaces in the names of all files in the current directory to underscores. Except it doesn't, and I think this is `ls`'s fault. The `for` loop is skipping over some files because `ls` changes the order according to which it sorts the files every time `mv` effectively modifies one of them. So I would need to isolate the names of the files in a way that does not rely on the "last modified" property. I thought of file size, but that won't work if there are two files that have the same size – e.g., I'm trying this code on a directory full of empty files.

*Is there a way to sort files with `ls` such that they remain in the same order as `mv` modifies their names?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to substitute your for loop with this one:

```
find . -type f | while read file
do
    OLDNAME="$file"
    NEWNAME=`echo $file| sed -e "s/${1}/${2}/g"`
    mv -v "$OLDNAME" "$NEWNAME"
done
```

Instead of running `ls` multiple times in order to get the file to rename,  you run find only once and iterate over the results

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler.

Comment: Yeah but I just realized it doesn't work with file names with spaces, let me work it out

Comment: Maybe using `awk`?

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: @piarston, this is supposed to be an exercise in bash scripting

Comment: @giobrach that's why I didn't post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks for sharing @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: No problem, that one of the most common *gotchas* `:)`

Comment: Thank you, David! That page is going to be useful.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using `mv -n` or `mv -i` in anything that does bulk renaming. That way, if there's a name conflict, bug, or whatever, you'll get an error or are-you-sure message instead of `mv` silently and irreversibly overwriting one of the conflicting files. Also, using `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file` and `echo "$file"` will avoid problems with some funny characters in filenames. Finally, this won't work right if any subfolders have spaces in their names, because it'll get confused about renaming the files vs. renaming the folders they're in.